# What does P mean in S.C.O.P.E.?

Tags: academic-writing, proofreading

I know I might be the only one learning this but what does P mean in S.C.O.P.E.? I tried accessing a website but could not due to restrictions put on by the owner.

Comment: Not only do I not know what the P in S.C.O.P.E means, I do not know what the entire word/acronym means. Please supply a little more context for the question. Please, tell us what you are trying to do, where and how you read/read about this concept, why and how this definition will help you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with writing.

Answer (score 2):

The P stands for **punctuation**.

### S.C.O.P.E.

A proofreading strategy: **Spelling**, **Capitalization**, **Order of words**, ***Punctuation***, **Express complete thoughts**

source: [12 Useful acronyms to help you with your writing](https://bighow.com/news/12-useful-acronyms-to-help-you-with-your-writing)

It's a *mnemonic* device to jog memory, not technically an *acronym*.